# How do I get to use img from custom hook object?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-custom-hooks

I'm trying to iterate over an array in a custom hook in order to use an img, however the img doesn't display.

What am I doing wrong as I don't want to manually create a img tag in order to display all images.

```
import useData from "../useData";
// import unwind from '../img/unwind-portfolio-img.png'

function Work() {

    const {projects} = useData();

    return ( 
        <section id="work">
            {projects && (
                <>
                    <img src={require(`${projects[0].img}`)} alt="" />
                </>
            )}
        </section>
     );
}

export default Work;
```

CUSTOME HOOK:

```
import unwind from './img/unwind-portfolio-img.png'
function useData() {

    const projects = [
        {
            site_name: 'Unwind',
            summary: 'An ecommerce book store built with React & Tailwind. View books, read their synopsis, and even add to your basket.',
            img: '../img/unwind-portfolio-img.png',
            // img: unwind,
            link: 'https://nmukassa1.github.io/unwind'
        }
    ]

    return { projects };
}

export default useData;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you don't return a state from your custom hook. Custom hooks should be composed of one or more hooks.

Update your `useData` hook like below:

```js
const initialProjects = [
  {
    site_name: "Unwind",
    summary:
      "An ecommerce book store built with React & Tailwind. View books, read their synopsis, and even add to your basket.",
    img: "../img/unwind-portfolio-img.png",
    link: "https://nmukassa1.github.io/unwind"
  }
];

function useData() {
  const [projects, setProjects] = React.useState(initialProjects);

  return { projects };
}

function Work() {
  const { projects } = useData();

  return (
    <section id="work">
      {projects && (
        <div>
          <h3>{projects[0].site_name}</h3>
          <div>{projects[0].summary}</div>
          <img src={`url(${projects[0].img})`} alt="" />
        </div>
      )}
    </section>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Work />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue comes from the `require` that you used to load the image. It won't work with a variable, it needs a static url to work.

However, you should be able to use this instead:

```js
<img src={projects[0].img} alt="" />
```

Don't forget to make sure that the image is available at this path and that the file is included when you will build and deploy your application.